# What do you call the thing you get at the hospital when you break your leg, etc.?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

When you break your leg or any of your appendages you get a binding, you know, the white thing to fix your arm or leg. What is that called?

I find the words *gypsum*, *cast* and *plastery* in the dictionary but from searching pictures on Google these don't seem to be the right words. (Also, in what context do you use these?)

I want to find a picture on Google where a group of people got these bindings on their legs, arms, necks, etc. What is the right word?

Comment: @tchrist, I'm three month's late, but I was going to say the same thing: :-)

Comment: @tchrist, your nationality is showing!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Generally, that "white thing" is called a [*cast*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cast?show=1&t=1331414899) (see definition 6c).

> A rigid casing (as of fiberglass or of gauze impregnated with plaster of paris) used for immobilizing a usually diseased or broken part.

Like this:

[image: cast]

Comment: thanks. Now, what is the best term to search a group of people in casts ? If I use the terms "group cast" google find a bunch of movie related pictures, none of them in cast !

Comment: @Walkman It is unlikely that you will find such an image; it's not a very common thing to search for. Does it need to be a group?

Comment: @Walkman: Is that your real question, to find a group of people in casts? and so what term to use to search for it? Do you think there are ofte people with casts who hang out together? Search for 'patient osteopathy'. (as an aside, 'cast' also means the group of players in a theatrical performance)

Comment: @Mahnax I know it's rare, but it is findable :) and yes, I need a group.

Comment: @Walkman Well, if it is findable, then you can certainly manage. There are other things which require my attention, so I'd rather not spend time looking for an image of multiple people in casts.

Comment: @Mahnax my question is answered, the rest is my job, but thanks :)

Comment: [I found it :)](http://www.gaitways.com/art/TheCastParty.jpg)

Comment: @Walkman Alright, glad you figured it out.

Comment: Also it can be called a plaster cast, which might help searching, next time.

Comment: then I get a lot of statues :D

Comment: I love how your example of the "white thing" is red. :)

Comment: @MarkBeadles Heh, that may have been intentional…

Answer (score 6):

It's a [cast](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthopedic_cast), often made of plaster or fiberglass.

[image]